# JSON id position changed after populate second spinner with second AsyncTask

Tags: android, json, loops, android-asynctask, android-spinner

I've got a problem that I am really confused, doing so much debugging, but still cannot solve the problem.

`id_kecamatan = categoriesList.get(position).getId();` value changed when the second spinner generated with second Asynctask, which is not suppose to be happen, but if I'm not execute the code which is found in `public void onItemSelected` the value of ID position not changed, which is suppose to be happen, and if I'm not put this code I can't populate the second spinner because the second spinner is based on first spinner value. This problem causing multiple looping onSelectedItem. please help. thanks.

if I put this code down below, `categoriesList.get(position).getId();` is changed.

```
    if (cekspin != cekstatusspin1){
                    spinnerFood2.setEnabled(true);
                    id_kecamatan = categoriesList.get(position).getId();
                    Log.d("MASUK KE 2: ", "> " + id_kecamatan);
                    cekstatusspin1 = cekspin;
    
//run the second asynctask for second spinner
                    runMultipleAsyncTask2();
                    }
```

Here the complete code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    private Spinner spinnerFood;
    private Spinner spinnerFood2;
    // array list for spinner adapter
    private ArrayList<Category> categoriesList;
    private ArrayList<Category> categoriesList2;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    int id_kecamatan,id_kelurahan,vv;
    // API urls
    // Url to get all categories
    private String URL_CATEGORIES = "http://192.168.1.88/android_spinnner/get_categories.php";
    private String URL_CATEGORIES2 = "http://192.168.1.88/android_spinnner/get_kelurahan.php?id_kabupaten=";
    private String URL2 = URL_CATEGORIES2;
    TextView texji;
    String cekstatusspin1,cekspin,cekspin2,b= null;
    String nilai = "ada";
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        spinnerFood = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinFood);
        spinnerFood2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        spinnerFood2.setEnabled(false);
        categoriesList = new ArrayList<Category>();
        categoriesList2 = new ArrayList<Category>();

        texji = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
        // spinner item select listener
        spinnerFood.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        spinnerFood2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        runMultipleAsyncTask();

    }


    /**
     * Adding spinner data
     * */
    private void populateSpinner() {
        List<String> lables = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < categoriesList.size(); i++) {
            lables.add(categoriesList.get(i).getName());
        }
        // Creating adapter for spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);
        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        spinnerFood.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

    }


    /**
     * Adding spinner data
     * */
    private void populateSpinner2() {
        if (spinnerAdapter2 != null) {
            spinnerAdapter2 = null;
        }
        Log.d("adapter terakhir: ", "> " + spinnerAdapter2);

        List<String> lables2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        Log.d("lables2: ", "> " + lables2);
        lables2.clear();
        Log.d("lables2 clear: ", "> " + lables2);

        for (int i = 0; i < categoriesList2.size(); i++) {
            lables2.add(categoriesList2.get(i).getName());
        }
        // Creating adapter for spinner
        spinnerAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables2);

        spinnerAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Log.d("adapter terakhir: ", "> " + spinnerAdapter2);

        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        spinnerAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // attaching data adapter to spinner

        spinnerFood2.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter2);
    }



    private void runMultipleAsyncTask() // Run Multiple Async Task
    {
        GetCategories asyncTask = new GetCategories(); // First
        asyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    }
    private void runMultipleAsyncTask2() // Run Multiple Async Task//
    {
        GetCategories2 asyncTask2 = new GetCategories2(); // Second
        // Above Api Level 13
        asyncTask2.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    }

    //Start First Async Task:
    /**
     * Async task to get all food categories
     * */
    private class GetCategories extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Mengambil data KECAMATAN..");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            ServiceHandler jsonParser = new ServiceHandler();
            String json = jsonParser.makeServiceCall(URL_CATEGORIES, ServiceHandler.GET);
            Log.e("Response: ", "> " + json);

            if (json != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
                    if (jsonObj != null) {
                        JSONArray categories = jsonObj
                                .getJSONArray("categories");

                        for (int i = 0; i < categories.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject catObj = (JSONObject) categories.get(i);
                            Category cat = new Category(catObj.getInt("id"),
                                    catObj.getString("name"));
                            categoriesList.add(cat);
                            Log.d("kecamatan BBBBBA: ", "> " + id_kecamatan);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("JSON Data", "Didn't receive any data from server!");
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            populateSpinner();
        }
    }


    //Start Second Async Task:
    /**
     * Async task to get all food categories
     * */
    private class GetCategories2 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Mengambil data kELURAHAN..");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            ServiceHandler jsonParser2 = new ServiceHandler();

            String json2 = jsonParser2.makeServiceCall(URL2+cekspin, ServiceHandler.GET);
            String x = URL2+cekspin;
            Log.d("URL: ", "> " + x);


            if (json2 != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj2 = new JSONObject(json2);
                    if (jsonObj2 != null) {
                        JSONArray categories = jsonObj2
                                .getJSONArray("categories");

                        for (int i = 0; i < categories.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject catObj2 = (JSONObject) categories.get(i);
                            Category cat2 = new Category(catObj2.getInt("id"),
                                    catObj2.getString("kecamatan"));
                            categoriesList2.add(cat2);
                            Log.d("kecamatan BACKGOUNR: ", "> " + id_kecamatan);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.d("JSON3: ", "> " + json2);
            } else {
                Log.e("JSON Data", "Didn't receive any data from server!");
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            populateSpinner2();
        }
    }

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected (AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position,
        long id){
        Toast.makeText(
                getApplicationContext(),
                parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString() + " Selected",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("cekspinA: ", "> " + cekspin);
            Log.d("cekstatuspin1A: ", "> " + cekstatusspin1);


            Log.d("kecamatan Q: ", "> " + id_kecamatan);
            id_kecamatan = categoriesList.get(position).getId();
            Log.d("kecamatan Z: ", "> " + id_kecamatan);

//          cekspin = cekstatusspin1;

            Log.d("categorylist: ", "> " + categoriesList);
            cekspin = String.valueOf(id_kecamatan);
            texji.setText(cekspin);

            Log.d("cekspin B: ", "> " + cekspin);
            Log.d("cekstatuspin1 B: ", "> " + cekstatusspin1);

            if (cekspin != cekstatusspin1){
                spinnerFood2.setEnabled(true);
                id_kecamatan = categoriesList.get(position).getId();
                Log.d("MASUK KE 2: ", "> " + id_kecamatan);
                cekstatusspin1 = cekspin;
 //run the second asynctask for second spinner
                runMultipleAsyncTask2();
                }
            }
    @Override
        public void onNothingSelected (AdapterView < ? > arg0){
    }
}
```

logcat

```
05-29 22:14:43.747 7541-7612/info.androidhive.spinnermysql E/Response:: > {"categories":[{"id":"64","name":"Kecamatan Bombarai"},{"id":"65","name":"Kecamatan Fakfak"},{"id":"66","name":"Kecamatan Fakfak Barat"},{"id":"67","name":"Kecamatan Fakfak Tengah"},{"id":"68","name":"Kecamatan Fakfak Timur"},{"id":"69","name":"Kecamatan Karas"},{"id":"70","name":"Kecamatan Kokas"},{"id":"71","name":"Kecamatan Kramongmongga"},{"id":"72","name":"Kecamatan Teluk Patipi"}]}
05-29 22:14:43.937 7541-7541/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/cekspinA:: > null
05-29 22:14:43.937 7541-7541/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/cekstatuspin1A:: > null
05-29 22:14:43.937 7541-7541/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/kecamatan Q:: > 0
05-29 22:14:43.937 7541-7541/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/kecamatan Z:: > 64
05-29 22:14:43.937 7541-7541/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/categorylist:: > [info.androidhive.spinnermysql.Category@28f0463, info.androidhive.spinnermysql.Category@31cd3860, info.androidhive.spinnermysql.Category@35ce7119, info.androidhive.spinnermysql.Category@21b1f5de, info.androidhive.spinnermysql.Category@196383bf, info.androidhive.spinnermysql.Category@63d7a8c, info.androidhive.spinnermysql.Category@37cc05d5, info.androidhive.spinnermysql.Category@36391ea, info.androidhive.spinnermysql.Category@cd69cdb]
05-29 22:14:43.947 7541-7541/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/cekspin B:: > 64
05-29 22:14:43.947 7541-7541/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/cekstatuspin1 B:: > null
05-29 22:14:43.947 7541-7541/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/MASUK KE 2:: > 64
05-29 22:14:43.997 7541-7541/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/DisplayManager: DisplayManager()
05-29 22:14:44.007 7541-7640/info.androidhive.spinnermysql I/System.out: Thread-221084(ApacheHTTPLog):isSBSettingEnabled false
05-29 22:14:44.007 7541-7640/info.androidhive.spinnermysql I/System.out: Thread-221084(ApacheHTTPLog):isShipBuild true
05-29 22:14:44.007 7541-7640/info.androidhive.spinnermysql I/System.out: Thread-221084(ApacheHTTPLog):SMARTBONDING_ENABLED is false
05-29 22:14:44.007 7541-7640/info.androidhive.spinnermysql I/System.out: Thread-221084(ApacheHTTPLog):SmartBonding Enabling is false, SHIP_BUILD is true, log to file is false, DBG is false
05-29 22:14:44.037 7541-7640/info.androidhive.spinnermysql I/System.out: AsyncTask #2 calls detatch()
05-29 22:14:44.037 7541-7640/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/URL:: > http://192.168.1.88/android_spinnner/get_kelurahan.php?id_kabupaten=64
05-29 22:14:44.037 7541-7640/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/JSON3:: > {"categories":[{"id":"415","id2":"64","kecamatan":"Kelurahan\/Desa Bimajaya"},{"id":"416","id2":"64","kecamatan":"Kelurahan\/Desa Bumimoroh Indah"},{"id":"417","id2":"64","kecamatan":"Kelurahan\/Desa Mekar Sari"},{"id":"418","id2":"64","kecamatan":"Kelurahan\/Desa Onim Sari"},{"id":"419","id2":"64","kecamatan":"Kelurahan\/Desa Otoweri"},{"id":"420","id2":"64","kecamatan":"Kelurahan\/Desa Pinang Agung"},{"id":"421","id2":"64","kecamatan":"Kelurahan\/Desa Tomage"},{"id":"422","id2":"64","kecamatan":"Kelurahan\/Desa Warimo"},{"id":"423","id2":"64","kecamatan":"Kelurahan\/Desa Warisa Mulya\/Mulia"},{"id":"424","id2":"64","kecamatan":"Kelurahan\/Desa Wonodadi Mulya\/Mulia"}]}
05-29 22:14:44.127 7541-7541/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/adapter terakhir:: > null
05-29 22:14:44.127 7541-7541/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/lables2:: > []
05-29 22:14:44.127 7541-7541/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/lables2 clear:: > []
05-29 22:14:44.127 7541-7541/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/adapter terakhir:: > android.widget.ArrayAdapter@3e2349c1
05-29 22:14:44.167 7541-7541/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/cekspinA:: > 64
05-29 22:14:44.167 7541-7541/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/cekstatuspin1A:: > 64
05-29 22:14:44.167 7541-7541/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/kecamatan Q:: > 64
05-29 22:14:44.167 7541-7541/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/kecamatan Z:: > 64
05-29 22:14:44.167 7541-7541/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/categorylist:: > [info.androidhive.spinnermysql.Category@28f0463, info.androidhive.spinnermysql.Category@31cd3860, info.androidhive.spinnermysql.Category@35ce7119, info.androidhive.spinnermysql.Category@21b1f5de, info.androidhive.spinnermysql.Category@196383bf, info.androidhive.spinnermysql.Category@63d7a8c, info.androidhive.spinnermysql.Category@37cc05d5, info.androidhive.spinnermysql.Category@36391ea, info.androidhive.spinnermysql.Category@cd69cdb]
05-29 22:14:44.167 7541-7541/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/cekspin B:: > 64
05-29 22:14:44.167 7541-7541/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/cekstatuspin1 B:: > 64
05-29 22:14:47.387 7541-7541/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
05-29 22:14:48.467 7541-7541/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
05-29 22:14:48.627 7541-7541/info.androidhive.spinnermysql W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
05-29 22:14:48.647 7541-7541/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/cekspinA:: > 64
05-29 22:14:48.647 7541-7541/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/cekstatuspin1A:: > 64
05-29 22:14:48.647 7541-7541/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/kecamatan Q:: > 64
05-29 22:14:48.647 7541-7541/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/kecamatan Z:: > 65
05-29 22:14:48.647 7541-7541/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/categorylist:: > [info.androidhive.spinnermysql.Category@28f0463, info.androidhive.spinnermysql.Category@31cd3860, info.androidhive.spinnermysql.Category@35ce7119, info.androidhive.spinnermysql.Category@21b1f5de, info.androidhive.spinnermysql.Category@196383bf, info.androidhive.spinnermysql.Category@63d7a8c, info.androidhive.spinnermysql.Category@37cc05d5, info.androidhive.spinnermysql.Category@36391ea, info.androidhive.spinnermysql.Category@cd69cdb]
05-29 22:14:48.657 7541-7541/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/cekspin B:: > 65
05-29 22:14:48.657 7541-7541/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/cekstatuspin1 B:: > 64
05-29 22:14:48.657 7541-7541/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/MASUK KE 2:: > 65
05-29 22:14:48.687 7541-7972/info.androidhive.spinnermysql I/System.out: Thread-221086(ApacheHTTPLog):isSBSettingEnabled false
05-29 22:14:48.687 7541-7972/info.androidhive.spinnermysql I/System.out: Thread-221086(ApacheHTTPLog):isShipBuild true
05-29 22:14:48.687 7541-7972/info.androidhive.spinnermysql I/System.out: Thread-221086(ApacheHTTPLog):SMARTBONDING_ENABLED is false
05-29 22:14:48.687 7541-7972/info.androidhive.spinnermysql I/System.out: Thread-221086(ApacheHTTPLog):SmartBonding Enabling is false, SHIP_BUILD is true, log to file is false, DBG is false
05-29 22:14:48.737 7541-7972/info.androidhive.spinnermysql I/System.out: AsyncTask #3 calls detatch()
05-29 22:14:48.737 7541-7972/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/URL:: > http://192.168.1.88/android_spinnner/get_kelurahan.php?id_kabupaten=65
05-29 22:14:48.747 7541-7972/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/JSON3:: > {"categories":[{"id":"425","id2":"65","kecamatan":"Kelurahan\/Desa Fak Fak Selatan"},{"id":"426","id2":"65","kecamatan":"Kelurahan\/Desa Gewerpe"},{"id":"427","id2":"65","kecamatan":"Kelurahan\/Desa Kapaurtutin"},{"id":"428","id2":"65","kecamatan":"Kelurahan\/Desa Lusy Pkeri"},{"id":"429","id2":"65","kecamatan":"Kelurahan\/Desa Sekban"},{"id":"430","id2":"65","kecamatan":"Kelurahan\/Desa Sekru"},{"id":"431","id2":"65","kecamatan":"Kelurahan\/Desa Torea"},{"id":"432","id2":"65","kecamatan":"Kelurahan\/Desa Wagom"},{"id":"433","id2":"65","kecamatan":"Kelurahan\/Desa Fak Fak Utara"},{"id":"434","id2":"65","kecamatan":"Kelurahan\/Desa Dulan Pok Pok"},{"id":"435","id2":"65","kecamatan":"Kelurahan\/Desa Tanama"},{"id":"441","id2":"65","kecamatan":"Kelurahan\/Desa Werba"}]}
05-29 22:14:48.777 7541-7541/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/adapter terakhir:: > null
05-29 22:14:48.777 7541-7541/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/lables2:: > []
05-29 22:14:48.777 7541-7541/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/lables2 clear:: > []
05-29 22:14:48.777 7541-7541/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/adapter terakhir:: > android.widget.ArrayAdapter@16f81dd
05-29 22:14:48.817 7541-7541/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/cekspinA:: > 65
05-29 22:14:48.817 7541-7541/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/cekstatuspin1A:: > 65
05-29 22:14:48.817 7541-7541/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/kecamatan Q:: > 65
05-29 22:14:48.817 7541-7541/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/kecamatan Z:: > 64
05-29 22:14:48.817 7541-7541/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/categorylist:: > [info.androidhive.spinnermysql.Category@28f0463, info.androidhive.spinnermysql.Category@31cd3860, info.androidhive.spinnermysql.Category@35ce7119, info.androidhive.spinnermysql.Category@21b1f5de, info.androidhive.spinnermysql.Category@196383bf, info.androidhive.spinnermysql.Category@63d7a8c, info.androidhive.spinnermysql.Category@37cc05d5, info.androidhive.spinnermysql.Category@36391ea, info.androidhive.spinnermysql.Category@cd69cdb]
05-29 22:14:48.817 7541-7541/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/cekspin B:: > 64
05-29 22:14:48.817 7541-7541/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/cekstatuspin1 B:: > 65
05-29 22:14:48.817 7541-7541/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/MASUK KE 2:: > 64
05-29 22:14:48.857 7541-7976/info.androidhive.spinnermysql I/System.out: Thread-221087(ApacheHTTPLog):isSBSettingEnabled false
05-29 22:14:48.857 7541-7976/info.androidhive.spinnermysql I/System.out: Thread-221087(ApacheHTTPLog):isShipBuild true
05-29 22:14:48.857 7541-7976/info.androidhive.spinnermysql I/System.out: Thread-221087(ApacheHTTPLog):SMARTBONDING_ENABLED is false
05-29 22:14:48.857 7541-7976/info.androidhive.spinnermysql I/System.out: Thread-221087(ApacheHTTPLog):SmartBonding Enabling is false, SHIP_BUILD is true, log to file is false, DBG is false
05-29 22:14:48.887 7541-7976/info.androidhive.spinnermysql I/System.out: AsyncTask #4 calls detatch()
05-29 22:14:48.887 7541-7976/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/URL:: > http://192.168.1.88/android_spinnner/get_kelurahan.php?id_kabupaten=64
05-29 22:14:48.887 7541-7976/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/JSON3:: > {"categories":[{"id":"415","id2":"64","kecamatan":"Kelurahan\/Desa Bimajaya"},{"id":"416","id2":"64","kecamatan":"Kelurahan\/Desa Bumimoroh Indah"},{"id":"417","id2":"64","kecamatan":"Kelurahan\/Desa Mekar Sari"},{"id":"418","id2":"64","kecamatan":"Kelurahan\/Desa Onim Sari"},{"id":"419","id2":"64","kecamatan":"Kelurahan\/Desa Otoweri"},{"id":"420","id2":"64","kecamatan":"Kelurahan\/Desa Pinang Agung"},{"id":"421","id2":"64","kecamatan":"Kelurahan\/Desa Tomage"},{"id":"422","id2":"64","kecamatan":"Kelurahan\/Desa Warimo"},{"id":"423","id2":"64","kecamatan":"Kelurahan\/Desa Warisa Mulya\/Mulia"},{"id":"424","id2":"64","kecamatan":"Kelurahan\/Desa Wonodadi Mulya\/Mulia"}]}
05-29 22:14:48.907 7541-7541/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/adapter terakhir:: > null
05-29 22:14:48.907 7541-7541/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/lables2:: > []
05-29 22:14:48.907 7541-7541/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/lables2 clear:: > []
05-29 22:14:48.907 7541-7541/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/adapter terakhir:: > android.widget.ArrayAdapter@3e613650
05-29 22:14:48.927 7541-7541/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/cekspinA:: > 64
05-29 22:14:48.927 7541-7541/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/cekstatuspin1A:: > 64
05-29 22:14:48.927 7541-7541/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/kecamatan Q:: > 64
05-29 22:14:48.927 7541-7541/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/kecamatan Z:: > 64
05-29 22:14:48.937 7541-7541/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/categorylist:: > [info.androidhive.spinnermysql.Category@28f0463, info.androidhive.spinnermysql.Category@31cd3860, info.androidhive.spinnermysql.Category@35ce7119, info.androidhive.spinnermysql.Category@21b1f5de, info.androidhive.spinnermysql.Category@196383bf, info.androidhive.spinnermysql.Category@63d7a8c, info.androidhive.spinnermysql.Category@37cc05d5, info.androidhive.spinnermysql.Category@36391ea, info.androidhive.spinnermysql.Category@cd69cdb]
05-29 22:14:48.937 7541-7541/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/cekspin B:: > 64
05-29 22:14:48.937 7541-7541/info.androidhive.spinnermysql D/cekstatuspin1 B:: > 64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, i find a solution, the problem is on `onItemSelected` i just add this and problem solved!

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) parent;
     if(spinner.getId() == R.id.spinner1)
     {
       //do this                    
     }
     else if(spinner.getId() == R.id.spinner2)
     {
       //do this
     }
```